# How do you calculate parameter

Tags: javascript, function

```
function doWork() {  
  return function calculate(y) {
     return y + 1;
  }  
}  

var func = doWork();  
var x = func(5);  
document.write(x);
```

If var x= func(5), var func=dowork(?);
How do you calculate the "?"

And isn't y undefined in line 2

Comment: doWork returns a function. It is stored in func. Thereafter you use func(parameter) to do the calculations. Can you expand on your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's tackle this one bit at a time.

```
function doWork() {

}
```

This function stores and returns a nested function called calculate.

```
function doWork() {
    return function calculate(y) {
         return y + 1;
    }
}
```

Calculate accepts a parameter in this particular case it's being parsed an integer, simply adding 1 and returning it. In which case if I did `console.log(calculate(4))` I would receive the number 5, as I'm parsing in my value, referencing it as 'Y' in the function, adding 1 and simply returning it.

We're then storing the function `doWork()` in the variable `func`.

Followed by storing that variable `func` in to variable `x` but notice how we are parsing the number 5 when we call `var x = func(5)` since we have parsed it to the function `doWork()` we have access to it in our `calculate` function which is nested && being returned.

We can call `var x = func( /* whatever integer we like here */ )` and it will simple return the nested function, with your integer plus 1.

Comment: You could just remove the nested function and just call `calculate(integer here)`. It would help you understand it easier.

Comment: or does func()= doWork()

Comment: Since you've set func to equal doWork(), when you call func, it will run the function doWork.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/5283119) It will probably give you a better explanation.